# Produce unique items from multiple arrays in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to produce, within my header, a comma delimited string - Books, Furniture, DVDs.

I have multiple arrays which are produced as such:

**events.cats arrays**

```
40743: {id: "40743", catid: "2", catname: "Books"}
40747: {id: "40747", catid: "5", catname: "Furniture"}
40797: {id: "40797", catid: "2", catname: "Books"}
40833: {id: "40833", catid: "3", catname: "DVDs"}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.each(allevents, function(idx, event) {
    if (event.cats) {
        var allcatsthisweek = [];
        $.each(event.cats, function(idx, cat){
            if(allcatsthisweek.indexOf(cat.catname) === -1){
                allcatsthisweek.push(cat.catname);
            }
       });
    }
   $('#categories').text('Categories:' + allcatsthisweek);
});
```

I am struggling however to get the desired list. Currently I am only getting 'Books, DVDs' in my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the unique `catname` you can use `Set` after getting all the `catname` in an array.

```js
let data = {40743: {id: "40743", catid: "2", catname: "Books"},40747: {id: "40747", catid: "5", catname: "Furniture"},40797: {id: "40797", catid: "2", catname: "Books"}, 40833: {id: "40833", catid: "3", catname: "DVDs"}},
    result = [...new Set(Object.values(data).map(({catname}) => catname))];
console.log(result.join(','));
```